# JQuery Ajax returning [object object]

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to troubleshoot my PHP and JQuery but unable to do so. I've tried using an alert box and console.log  to capture the error.However, in the former I only receive [object object] and in the latter, nothing get's published to the console.

Jquery is calling a PHP script to register a user, but is unable to do so.:

```
$.ajax({   
type: 'POST',
url: '/study/scripts/register.php',
data: {firstName:firstName, lastName:lastName, email:email},
cache: false,
error: function(data) 
{
    alert(data);
    alert("Bad");
},
success: function(data) 
{
    alert(data);
    alert("Good");
}
});
```

PHP:

```
<?

require ('../include/config.php');

class regForm
    {
        //Constructor Function
        public function __construct() 
        {
            global $db;
            $db = new dbConnect;

            //Error Flag
            global $errorFlag;
            $errorFlag = 0;
        }
    /*other input validation functions here. They work fine and have been tested*/
    }

    $form = new regForm;

    $tableName = 'user';
    $columnName = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email_id');
    $columnValue = array($firstName, $lastName, $email);
    $db->insert($tableName, $columnName, $columnValue);
?>
```

**Update:**

I enabled preserve log and 'LogXMLhttprequests' in the console settings after which i have received this error:

```
VM174 jquery.min.js:2 XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost/study/scripts/register.php".<br>
    send    @   VM174 jquery.min.js:2<br>
    ajax    @   VM174 jquery.min.js:2<br>
    Register    @   VM187 register.js:86<br>
    onclick @   (index):121<br>
```

Comment: replace this line `alert(data);` with this `console.log(data);` and you should read more details about `alert` function

Comment: try console.log(data.d);

Comment: just stringify it only for view purpose JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: Do as the above comments suggests. `alert()` can't show complex types while `console.log()` can. However, I don't actually see your PHP outputting anything so I'm not sure what result you expect your callback to get?

Comment: thanks @Kiranramchandarn. I replaced data with console.lg(data.d) and it does reflect an error but the error stays on the console only for a second. Is there a way to keep it there for longer or save it so I can read the complete error?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the PHP will return a value 1 on successful registration and the success function of JQuery will give a custom message like 'Registration Successful'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form was loaded in a modal so had to prevent it's default behavior. Added event.preventDefault(); to resolve the issue.

Thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment you should replace this line `alert(data);` with this `console.log(data);`

**Some Details:**

**`alert()` function detail:** Specifies the text to display in the alert box, or an object converted into a string and displayed [(alert definition Reference)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp) (single variable and not display array)

So, when you pass array into `alert()` function then it's display `object object`.

If you want to display array then you should used `console.log()` function

Comment: Update:

I enabled preserve log and 'LogXMLhttprequests' in the console settings after which i have received this error:

VM174 jquery.min.js:2 XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost/study/scripts/register.php".
    send @ VM174 jquery.min.js:2
    ajax @ VM174 jquery.min.js:2
    Register @ VM187 register.js:86
    onclick @ (index):121

Answer (score 0):

[object Object] is basically an array

Try this code:

```
success: function( data ) {

       alert(JSON.stringify(data));
       //or
       console.log(data);

    },
```

This should show you the array, which will give you the ability to better select the elements to output

Comment: Hi @fullstack i put the error as an update with the original post. I'm unable to understand what the error is. If you could provide more details, it will be great. Thanks.